# Static block into a specific kind of page

Tags: static-block

I need to show an element wrote in HTML into a footer page, only if you're in a specific page ( website homepage, category pages, search results and product pages).

I don't want use statics blocks because the element that I've to show is a simple image with a small amount of text, so the best way that i think to add an "if" that shows the code only if you're in the pages quoted upstairs, but I don't know how can I write the "if condition".

I'm waiting for the answers.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structures to determine requested page
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();` for route name
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();` for action name
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();` for controller name
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerModule();` for module with namespace
`Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();` for id of cms page

for example if you need to output your cms block only on Terms and Conditions page you can use

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerModule() == 'Mage_Cms' && Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'terms-and-conditions'): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_cms_block_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

in app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml

Hope it will be usefull for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.

Unfortunately I don't understand well (I don't know a lot about php) how can I write down the php code, I tried it but it doesn't work.

May you help me?